# Google Cloud Build: Moving files

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform, yaml, cloud, move

I want to move the file `index.js` from the root of the project to the `dist/project_name`. This is the step from `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    args: ['-c', 'mv', 'index.js', 'dist/project_name']
```

But the step is failing with the next error:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `bash -c`, I think you need to encapsulate the entire "script" in a string:

```
args: ['-c', 'mv index.js dist/project_name']
```

My personal preference (and it's just that), is to not embed JSON (`[...]`) in YAML. This makes the result in this case slightly clearer and makes it easier to embed a multiline script:

```
args:
- bash
- -c
- |
  mv index js dist/project_name
```

> **NOTE** tools like [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com/) will do this for you too.